# How to access USB stick content from VMWare running Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: usb, mount, vmware-player, ubuntu-10.10

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 via VMWare under Windows 7. I have followed the procedure to install the USB stick. It is now connected to the host.

However, I don't know how to access the content of the stick. My Google research indicates that this may be a mounting issue. I read somewhere that I should check /proc/bus/usb, but the usb directory does not exist in /proc/bus. Unfortunately, I am not a Linux expert at this.

The ultimate issue I am trying to solve is the one describe [here](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/175165). I am trying to use vi to create ~/.vmware/config, but it is virtually impossible to use vi, since I don't have access to the arrow keys (chicken & egg problem). I have created the config file on my usb stick and want to copy it where it should be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to tranfert the config file: sharing folders between Vista 7 and Ubuntu inside VMware (see [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html) for the procedure).

I still have not found a solution for my USB stick issue, but... I can move forward!

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same question and found the solution on the [VMWare forum](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/201617). This is a different solution from sharing folders between the host and guest OS as described above. It's an alternative if you don't want to use folder sharing.

Essentially, you need to find your USB drive under *Virtual Machine -> Removable Devices*, and click *connect*. Alternatively you can do this by clicking on the USB drive's icon on the bottom of the VMWare window. This works with VMWare 4.0.4.

[image: VMWare window running Ubuntu 11.10 server]

After "connecting" the drive, then you have to mount it with the standard mount command in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

First check the command : `sudo fdisk -l` to find which device file is your USB drive (sda,sdc,sdb)

Then use this commands to mount it somewhere:

1. `mkdir /media/usb`  (creates directory where usb will be mounted)
2. `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb`

Then if you want to copy some content from usb, you can do simply:

`cp /media/usb/file.txt /path/to/dest/`

And befre removing the USB drive, unmount it:

`umount -l /media/usb`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply drag'n'droping the file from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: I have installed the server version of Ubuntu which does not come with a GUI...

Answer (score 0):

> the ultimate issue I am trying to solve is the one describe here.
>   I am trying to use vi to create ~/.vmware/config, but it is virtually
>   impossible to use vi, since I don't have access to the arrow keys

You can use an editor which does not use the arrow key. **One classic example of that is vi** which uses <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> for navigation in command mode.

> I have created the config file on my USB stick and want to copy it where
>   it should be.

For that you want to 'plug the USB pendrive' into the guest machine.

At the moment is is plugged into the host (windows 7) and you can only access it on the host. To mount it in a VM you want to disconnect it from the win7 host and connect it to your Ubuntu VM. There is an option for this is the menus under removable devices.

After that you can mount it as usual in Ubuntu.